# Simple Java If/Else if Statement Unfunctional

Tags: java, if-statement

I was working on my game I am making, when I came across an error. My if/else if statement skips right to the else if statement, even if it shouldn't.

```
String neededCredits = "200";

 if(Peeamnt.getText() == neededCredits) {
        System.out.println("You can afford this");
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(BuyPoopButton,
        "You have unlocked the Poop Button for 200 Pee Credits!",
        "Toilet Master",
        JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
}
    else if((!(Peeamnt.getText() == neededCredits))) {
        System.out.println("You cannot afford this");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(BuyPoopButton,
                "You do not have enough Credits to buy this!\n"
                + "To buy it, you need 200 Pee Credits!",
                "Toilet Master",
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```

Even if the text of Peeamnt is an even 200, the code will jump to the else if statement, telling me that I don't have 200 Pee Credits. (The game I am making included a lot of **toilet** humor.) Anyway, if anyone sees the error I have in this code, please let me know. Let me know if you need more code.

Comment: Partly. I guess .equals() { fixed my problem. Thanks. ;)

Comment: There's probably no need to call `getText` twice.  If `neededCredits.equals(Peeamnt.getText())` is false, then the `else` part will automatically happen.  You don't need to put the `neededCredits` test in there again.  And if `getText()` actually does something like wait for the user to type something in, then the code you posted will wait for input twice which is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 2):

With a Java `String` object, the `==` operator doesn't compare the string value.
Try changing the first `if` comparison to:

`if(Peeamnt.getText().equals(neededCredits)) {`

You will need to do something similar for the `else if` as well.

Comment: Better would be `neededCredits.equals(Peeamnt.getText())`, since we know for sure that `neededCredits` is not null.

Answer (score 1):

Strings are objects. Objects have a reference. Two String objects containing the same sequence of characters may not be the same object, thus having different references. The `==` operator (generally) checks for reference equality.

To compare the character sequence of two String objects for equality, you have the `equals` method. So use `Peeamnt.getText().equals(neededCredits)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

String is an Object. Comparing Object, you have to use `equals` to judge whether the Object content is same. Using `==` is to compare Object reference

Answer (score 1):

Use **equals** method to compare String object, because **==** operator means you compare object base on memory address. Always remember to never use **==** to compare objects in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use equals method if the `getText()` returns a string don 't use `==` sign. I suppose that `getText() returns a`String` object.

FYI: Double equal sign is used to see if two Objects are the same 
     and TO check if the objects has the same value `equals()` method should be used. Note: The objects that You compare with `equals()` should override it otherwise the results are corrupted, and the last thing when You overrides`equals()` method remember to override `hashCode()` too.

Answer (score 0):

Use method equals to compare String object, because == operator means you compare object base on memory address.
* never use == to compare object.

```
String neededCredits = "200";

 if(neededCredits.equals(Peeamnt.getText()) {//compare following you never see, because  nullPointerException "neededCredits" always has value :-)
        System.out.println("You can afford this");
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(BuyPoopButton,
        "You have unlocked the Poop Button for 200 Pee Credits!",
        "Toilet Master",
        JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
}
    else if((!(neededCredits.equals(Peeamnt.getText()))) {
        System.out.println("You cannot afford this");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(BuyPoopButton,
                "You do not have enough Credits to buy this!\n"
                + "To buy it, you need 200 Pee Credits!",
                "Toilet Master",
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```